# How to retrieve page ids based on type using FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I want to retrieve page ids of all those pages whose type is Musician/Band. I tried to retrive it from page table as

**SELECT page_id from page where type='MUSICIAN/BAND'**

but it is not allowing that.Its giving **error:**

Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column.

How to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply cannot do that query.  You need to include at least one of the indexable columns in your query (page_id or name).